# How to add user to QBRTCSession if it is already established

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have audio chat session (QBRTCSession) object with 3 QBUUsers in it. I need possibility to add another QBUUser in that call session. Can I do this without creating new session and calling to all users again?

Currently I create session in QBRTCClient this way

```
NSArray *opponentsIDs = @[@2145, @2144, @2143];
QBRTCSession* session = 
[QBRTCClient.instance createNewSessionWithOpponents:opponentsIDs
withConferenceType:conferenceType];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now you should recreate session.

This feature is planned for future releases.